# Javascript, Given some conditionals, All posible combinations of arrays in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, combinations, cartesian-product

I have this array:

```
[[1, 3, 7][2, 1, 0][2, 5, 4][3, 5, 0][4, 2, 4][4, 5, 7][5, 3, 0][6, 3, 7]]
```

I want to have all possible combinations of arrays having two conditions:

1. That the element 0 is never the same
2. That the element 2 is different, without repetition

My product should be responsive to different inputs of 3 value arrays, and in this case, it should look like this:

```
[
[[1, 3, 7][2, 1, 0][4, 2, 4]]
[[1, 3, 7][2, 5, 4][3, 5, 0]]
[[1, 3, 7][2, 5, 4][5, 3, 0]]
[[1, 3, 7][3, 5, 0][4, 2, 4]]
... and so on
]
```

Hope you could understand the issue and give some help.

Comment: please add your code. what goes wrong?

Comment: I do not have a clue how to do it, my code can be seen here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/trastes-ejemplo-2 , but I actually haven't found a way to make this kind of organization, I did it with strings instead of arrays, but I do need it without using strings. I do not have a code for this part yet, just like attempts with for loops, but nothing serious enough to share.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.